# jQuery animate scrollTop is not working in latest android version Nougat

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have this code to scroll to a position on page load. But this does not seem to work in Android Nougat version. Works well in Android 6.0.1

```
$('body.catalog-category-view').animate({ scrollTop: '510px' }, 500);
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using below code:

```
$('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 510
}, 800);
```

Restricted the animation to a particular page having this class in body (catalog-category-view) by placing condition like this:

```
var catalogList = $('.catalog-category-view');
if(catalogList.length){
    $('body,html').animate({
       scrollTop: 510
    }, 800);
}
```